# ms-access: best way to add trailing character to every record

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

i will be importing a table with data. one of the columns called CAR will look something like this:

```
mercedes,ford,toyota
```

for every record in the DB i will need to add a comma `,` to the end of the string like:

```
mercedes,ford,toyota,
```

since i will be programmatically importing the table, what is the best way to add this trailing comma to every record?

Comment: Is there some reason you want to waste time continuing to propagate badly structured data?

Comment: For "badly structured data", MS-Access could be the way to go ;)
http://www.theregister.co.uk/2006/07/18/multivalued_datatypes_access/print.html

Comment: Multi valued fields are for use with Sharepoint, that is an old article. "`Even though what you see and work with appears to be a single field, the values are actually stored independently and managed in hidden, system tables. The Access database engine handles this for you, automatically separating the data and bringing it back together again to surface the values in one field.`" -- http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/access-help/guide-to-multivalued-fields-HA001233722.aspx

Comment: @onedaywhen: data can be structured badly in any database. Bad data structure is pilot error, not something inherent to the database engine.

Comment: @David-W-Fenton: The Access team chose to expose multi-value types in the Access UI, expose them in ACEDAO library, etc. So if the manufacturer of said airplane adds "Self destruct" cockpit button, its pilot error when it gets pressed?!

Comment: @Remou: the Access team bigged up multi-valued types as a new feature in Access2007 and that 'old' article is contemporary with that. Have the Access team had a change of heart?

Comment: The support in the ACE for MV fields is there because it's required for Access to be able to work with Sharepoint lists. If you aren't linked to Sharepoint lists, you won't be using the MV support in the user interface *UNLESS* you've created MV fields in a Jet/ACE data store. In that case, you're making the error of using something that's better done explicitly, i.e., MV fields are implicitly implemented as proper N:N join structure, but not exposed that way. A programmer knows enough to build that himself, and has no need for MV fields.

Comment: Additionally, Access/Jet/ACE and every other database engine/development environment places no restrictions on the user's ability to create denormalized tables or inefficient tables or any number of things that are obvious mistakes. It's up to the person designing the schema to decide what the best way to do it for the particular application is, and if they make errors in designing the schema, that's not the fault of Access or any database -- it's pure pilot error.

Comment: @David-W-Fenton: the "programmer" of which you speak is indeed a noble beast; anyone we know? ;) However, this is Microsoft we're talking about and the stuff they put in the Access Help doesn't exactly discourage mortal users from using these MV fields e.g. I quote, "You should consider creating a multivalued field when you want to: Store a multiple valued selection from a list of choices, and that list of choices is relatively small." SharePoint integration doesn't make it to the top of the list. The prosecution rests.

Comment: MV fields are the least of the sins against proper schema design that novices are likely to make. This is a site for programmers, not receptionists who use Access for point and click, so I thought we would be talking about the responsible use of tools by programmers. YMMV.

Comment: @David-W-Fenton: "receptionists who use Access for point and click" -- you previously admitted this is how you write your SQL code, lol ! Dave, mines back no sugar, I think the phone is ringing...

Comment: I have never said I use point and click to write SQL. I do use the tools available in the QBE, some of which are point and click and some of which are not. I frequently dip into the SQL view and write things that can't be represented in the QBE, but I don't do that until I have to. This seems efficient to me, and is well beyond what the receptionist is capable of. The last sentence of your comment s gibberish so far as I'm concerned, and I really don't know what your point is in trying to have this kind of discussion. It doesn't do anything at all to improve SO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to update every record in a single UPDATE, try:

```
UPDATE YourTable SET CAR=CAR & ","
```

to update only a certain row try:

```
UPDATE YourTable SET CAR=CAR & "," WHERE {{some condition here, like ID=12}}
```